# When Select distinct From Features give Error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list?

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I work on SQL server 2012 query I face issue:

> error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

How to solve this issue please?

In my solution I have more Features Repeated in DkFeatureName  so I need to select only distinct.

Features and this will prevent repeated columns.

```
create table #nonparametricdata
(
    PART_ID nvarchar(50) ,
    CompanyName  nvarchar(50),
    PartNumber nvarchar(50),
    DKFeatureName nvarchar(100),
    Tempvalue nvarchar(50),
    StatusId int,
    DisplayOrder int,
    FlagAllow bit
)

insert into #nonparametricdata
values
('1222','Honda','silicon','package','15.50Am',3,4,0),
('1900','MERCEIS','GLASS','family','90.00Am',2,3,1),
('5000','TOYOTA','alominia','source','70.20kg',3,5,0),
('8000','MACDA','motor','parametric','50.40kg',2,1,1),
('8900','JEB','mirror','noparametric','75.35kg',2,6,0),
('8000','MACDA','motor','parametric','50.40kg',2,2,1)

DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Header = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT distinct ', ' +  case when A.splitFlag = 1 then ''''+A.DKFeatureName +''' as '''+A.DKFeatureName+''','''+ A.DKFeatureName + 'Units'  +''' as ''' + A.DKFeatureName +'Units' +'''' else ''''+A.DKFeatureName +''' as ''' + A.DKFeatureName +''''    end
            FROM #FinalTable A
            where StatusId=2
        
            ORDER BY DisplayOrder
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
    SELECT @Header
```

Comment: Can you show your expected results please.

Comment: Your example SQL is not executable. There is no definition of `#FinalTable`

Comment: If the column doesn't appear in the select list of the `distinct`, that can mean that there are *2 or more* rows which are being condensed down into a single output row and *they can have different `DisplayOrder` values* - the server is quite rightly telling you that it wouldn't know how to then sort such a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using DISTINCT, use a GROUP BY clause. This allows you to ORDER BY an aggregated missing column. Principle

```
SELECT A, B
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY MAX(C)
```

Or simply do what the error message suggest: Include `DisplayOrder` in the select list.

```
SELECT distinct DisplayOrder, ', ' +  case when A.splitFlag = 1 then ''''+A.DKFeatureName ...
```

The problem is that DISTINCT may discard some rows. So if `DisplayOrder` is different within these otherwise equal rows, which one of them should be used for sorting? With GROUP BY, you can specify which one. In my example it would be `MAX(DisplayOrder)`, i.e., the largest within otherwise distinct rows. It also could be `MIN()` or `AVG()` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of error messages, I would say that this one is about as self explanatory as it gets. To explain why this is the case, consider the following data:

```
Name        DisplayOrder
-----------------------------
Name 1          1
Name 1          4
Name 2          3
Name 2          2
```

Then we want distinct names, ordered by `DisplayOrder`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM T
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```

Since there are two `DisplayOrder` values for each name, SQL Server doesn't know which to pick, and which one is picked will affect the order of results, so **YOU** must tell it which one to pick.

I would usually swap out `DISTINCT` for `GROUP BY` and use an aggregate:

```
SELECT Name
FROM T
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MIN(DisplayOrder);
```

In your case I think you would end up with something like:

```
DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Header = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' +  case when A.splitFlag = 1 then ''''+A.DKFeatureName +''' as '''+A.DKFeatureName+''','''+ A.DKFeatureName + 'Units'  +''' as ''' + A.DKFeatureName +'Units' +'''' else ''''+A.DKFeatureName +''' as ''' + A.DKFeatureName +''''    end
            FROM #FinalTable A
            where StatusId=2
            GROUP BY A.SplitFlag, A.DKFeatureName
            ORDER BY MIN(DisplayOrder)
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
    SELECT @Header
```